# Cannot change click speed and single click becomes a double click

Tags: 20.04, mouse, button

I'm using Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS, GNOME Version 3.36.8.

Since the latest two upgrades the mouse has started doing this: more than half the time a single click becomes a double click. This makes it very difficult to use the mouse, which is a plain Dell mouse that came bundled with the PC. After the preinstalled Windows died, I switched to new disk drives and installed Ubuntu, which worked brilliantly until now.

The suggestion has been to go to *Mouse & Touchpad* and change the clicking sensitivity, however that option no longer exists.

So what can I do to fix the issue?

Comment: This is possibly a mouse hardware problem. Please, replace it with a spare mouse and see if the problem persists.

Comment: I replaced the mouse and the issue still continued.
I've rebooted and I'll let you know.

Comment: Brand new mouse, never used, and half the time when I single click it still double clicks.

Comment: Try to change the "Double-Click Delay" setting in **Settings → Accessibility → Pointing & Clicking**. The same can be done with `dconf-editor` under **/org/gnome/settings-daemon/peripherals/mouse/**

Answer (score 1):

Open Settings, Select "Universal Access Tab"
go to "Pointing and Clicking"
Adjust "Double-Click Delay" slider

Answer (score 0):

Or if you can't single-click at all, use the command line:

```
dconf write /org/gnome/settings-daemon/peripherals/mouse/double-click 200
```

Comment: I've applied this and it seems to be better.